# VBS script does not work properly from Task Scheduler in Windows 10

Tags: windows, vba, batch-file, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I have a windows server designed to perform mail merges for postal letters.
A outside server generates xls data sheets and SFTPS them to my windows server, along with a JSON file with further instructions:

- The Letter to merge with (docx file)
- An E-mail address to send a PDF of the merged letters.

The script works like this:
1. Constantly(every 60 seconds) monitor directory for JSON files. -> 
2. If there is a JSON file, parse it. ->
3. Find XLS file related to that JSON file ->
4. Run VBA/ EXCEL macro to mail merge XLS and the letter into a PDF ->
5. Email PDF to appropriate contact ->
6. Move XLS file to Processed Folder
7. Move JSON file to PRocessed Folder

If I run it manually from the command line it works just fine.  However, If I run it from Task Scheduler, either with "RUN" or automatically when the machine restarts or when a given user logs in the script fails.  Steps 1, 2, and 3 work.  The VBA code/ Macro fails to work.

I'm hoping this can be resolved through configuration of Task Scheduler.  Here is my current setup:

Script runs from a bat file, the message script keeps a CMD window open that explains what the script is doing:

```
cscript C:\automerge\message.vbs
cscript C:\automerge\automerge.vbs >> C:\automerge\logs.log
```

Task Scheduler Settings:
Run only when user is logged on
Run with Highest Privileges
Configure for Windows 10 (tried using 7 and 8 too)

Trigger:
Trigger at logon - Enabled

Action:
Start a program
Details:
"C:\AutoMerge\JSON Watch.bat"

Conditions:
Start the task only if computer is on AC power
Stop if computer switches to battery power

Settings:
Allow Task to run on demand
If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop

Can anyone give me advice on how to change the scheduled task or batch file to get this to work?

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: @Noodles ideally this does belong in the SuperUser stack as it's a general windows scheduling task question versus code question.

Comment: Maybe not. In particular I want to see if any config dependent things are being used like mapped drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Noodles was right it was something in the code.

I created a file system object and used it to get a File.Name.   Then I passed this File.Name(without the path) to a function that parses the JSON in the file.  This worked just fine when I manually ran it.

```
JSONExists(File.Name)
```

In order to run properly from Task Scheduler I had to make sure it passed the entire file name including the path.

```
FPath = "C:\Automerge\"    
JSONExists(FPath & File.Name)
```

I'm not exactly sure why I need the whole path with Task Scheduler and not when I run manually, but at least now I have a good rule of thumb.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing like this instead of calling the batch file directly.

32-bit

```
Action: "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\AutoMerge\JSON Watch.bat"
```

or 64-bit

```
Action: "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c C:\AutoMerge\JSON Watch.bat"
```

If it is 64-bit... update your cscript to execute %SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\cscript.exe